# turning MySQL values into PHP variable when using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I can get a value from the database and echo it out like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT id 
          FROM table1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $res['id'];
```

Although, when using any sort of join an issue occurs

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.id,
               table2.id 
          FROM table1
          JOIN table2";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $res['id'];
```

I can't echo out the value like I previously could with a single table.

How do I echo out the id from a specific table, either table1 or table2? I tried `echo $res['table1.id'];` but that doesn't seem to work out

Comment: Try a rename of an id via `as`, e.g. `table1.id as id_one` and check if that works.

Comment: var_dump($res) and see how can u access to them, if values it rewrite user AS kay in query

Comment: use `var_dump($res);` so you can see waht the database returns

Comment: Use aliases, `SELECT table1.id as t1_id, table2.id as t2_id`. You probably also should add an `on` clause so the query knows how to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.id as id,
           table2.id as id1 
      FROM table1
      JOIN table2";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo $res['id1']."--".$res['id'];
```